# How do you get nativeID for react-native InputAccessoryView

Tags: react-native

I am following the documentation on `InputAccessoryView` here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/03/22/building-input-accessory-view-for-react-native.html

with code:

```
export default class Debug extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: 'Hello world from debug'};
  }

  render() {

    const inputAccessoryViewID = "uniqueID";

    const accesory = (
        <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({text: 'You didnt enter the magic word'})}
            title="Reset Text"
          />
        </InputAccessoryView>
    )

    return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="interactive">
              <TextInput
                style={{
                  padding: 10,
                  paddingTop: 50,
                }}
                inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
                value={this.state.text}
              />
            </ScrollView>

            {accesory}

        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But the docs do not explain where I can get this id `uniqueID`. Is it something I can find in xcode?

Comment: That example no longer seems to work in RN 0.57.  Try https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/RNTester/js/InputAccessoryViewExample.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputAccessoryView` is expecting a unique id for [`nativeID`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/inputaccessoryview#nativeid) property to match with a `TextInput` that has the same unique id set on `inputAccessoryViewID` property. This way it knows to activate on that input. This way you can have different `InputAccessoryView`s for different `TextInput`s.

> **nativeID**
>
> An ID which is used to associate this `InputAccessoryView` to specified
>   `TextInput`(s).

So that `uniqueID` is some string that is unique which you can set to anything yourself to match with the `TextInput`.